# WordPress wp_query order by meta_value incorrect order numerically

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a simple web application that is running off of WordPress to store and display high scores for a game. The scores are displayed highest to lowest on a page. Everything seems to work great, until one of the scores goes above 999, in which case it is placed in the wrong order.

In my application scores are saved as a string within a `meta_value`. I am querying posts and ordering them based off of this value.

Here are the args that I am passing to `wp_query`:

```
$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'scoreboard',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'score',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
);
```

Scores are returned in a like way. Note that `1000` is placed after `123`:

```
777, 700, 601, 600, 567, 400, 123, 1000, 1
```

Can someone offer an explanation as to why this may be happening?

Comment: try david answer. its correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sorting by string representation of the field 1000 is lower than 12 in string terms. Same as when sorting words ABBOTT will be higher than AA.

try

```
$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'scoreboard',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'score',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
);
```

Comment: Aha! I should have known this one. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: For me it sorts the score in this order : 90, 90, 9, 9, 87, 84,8, etc....
What wrong I could be doing?